# Domain name goes to router login on the same network and no response from outside

Tags: networking, router, dns, proxy

This is not a duplicate of [DNS: Domain name goes to router when on the network, not the web server](https://superuser.com/questions/292133/dns-domain-name-goes-to-router-when-on-the-network-not-the-web-server).

I have a domain `putimas.com`. When open the browser with this URL, I get a router login page from my ISP. I am assuming this is because we are on the same network. But when I browse with `tor` or any annonymouse proxy site with the same url I get a no response. I used `http://ping.eu/ping/` link to ping and got no response. I am a beginner on this field. Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

**Edit:** My web server is working perfect. And I get a static ethernet connection from my ISP.

Comment: The reason you get the router config page from within the network _is_ the same reason as the answer you linked.  The reason you can't find the site from outside the network is because you haven't opened or forwarded ports on the router.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you can browse outbound, but not reach your own site in the opposite direction?   Those connections are two different things, as one is outbound and the other is inbound.  As far as port forwarding, specific instruction will depend on your router model, but in general you need to forward Port 80 (http) to the specific internal IP of the computer with the webserver.

Comment: @Tyson, But I can browse web from my server. So I assume port 80 is open. And if I am wrong, would you post some detail of how to open or forward ports on the router? And router is `MikroTik`

Comment: Inbound and outbound connections are different.  as for port forwarding: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=MikroTik+Port+Forwarding

Comment: @Tyson Thank you for the comment. This should give me a starting point.

Comment: On a high level, keep in mind that the local computer will have an internal network IP that is different than your external IP address.  You want to forward Port 80 to the internal IP.  This allows requests from ExternalIP:port80 to reach InternalIP:port80.  There are many variations, but that is the simple straight forward logic.